# Replace string if specific characters / string are included at the beginning and end

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Background: the init string is always different (but it contains aa== at the beginning and ==b at the end)

example:

```
var string = 'aa==1234^&==b'
var string = 'aa==hello==b'
var string = 'aa==world!==b'
```

How to replace the string in the middle part? ? ?

```
string.replace(????, 'TestOK')
```

result:

```
var string = 'aa==TestOK==b'
var string = 'aa==TestOK==b'
var string = 'aa==TestOK==b'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing everything between the `==`s should do it:

```js
const transform = str => str.replace(/(?<===)[^=]+(?===)/g, 'TestOK');
console.log(transform('aa==1234^&==b'));
```

Comment: Nice, but would you add some explanation for (?<===)[^ =] +(?===)? I am not familiar with Regex.

Comment: `?<=` is lookbehind. So it matches the position preceded by `==`. Then `?=` is lookahead. It matches the position followed by `==`. `[^=]` matches anything but an `=`. `+` matches the previous token one or more times.